# Is it possible to import c# classes from dll in a vb.net dll?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

- IDE: VS2010
- Framework.net: 4.0

I created a c# dll project under Visual Studio 2010, with several public classes, and I would like to use its classes inside another dll project, but written in vb.net.

In the vb.net dll project, I referenced the built c# dll, but impossible to import the c# classes. The namespace of the c# dll is even not recognized.

What must I do to see my c# classes?
If this is possible.

Example of class of my c# dll (namespace MyCSharpDll):

```
namespace MyCSharpNamespace {
  public class MyCSharpClass {
    public void Test() {}
  }
}
```

Example in a file of my vb.net dll:

```
Imports MyCSharpDll.MyCSharpNamespace
```

VS2010 indicates an error saying that MyCSharpDll is unknown or no public member.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should rewrite your imports

Imports MyCSharpNamespace

without 'MyCSharpDll'  part

Comment: Very good!! But I don't understand why I cannot write the full imports statement in my case. Note: At beginning, I tried this statement, but I didn't work, now yes.

Comment: Because 'MyCSharpDll' isn't a namespace.

Comment: it was not clear in my message but MyCSharpDll is the root namespace of the dll, sorry.

Comment: @Alain - C# doesn't have the concept of a "root" namespace like VB does.  C# has a "default" namespace that is used in new files.  Whatever is on the namespace statement is the namespace for the class.

Answer (score 4):

You asked: "I created a c# dll project under Visual Studio 2010, with several public classes, and I would like to use its classes inside another dll project, but written in vb.net."

**YES you can do it.**

Just add to that DLL reference and that's it!

Comment: I put the reference to the dll, as indicated in my message. Maybe in the c# project must I set something?

Comment: Almost right. The imported DLL needs to be CLS compliant and compiled against the same runtime version in order to be imported successfully.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, with the answer of @Steve, yes.

Comment: @Oded, they were both CLS compliant and compiled against the same runtime version.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the dll in question is [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx) and compiled against the same runtime version, you should be able to use it without a problem.

If either (or both) of these conditions are not met, you will not be able to use the imported DLL.

Make sure the `Import` directive uses the namespace as defined in the assembly metadata - look at your C# project properties to see what the default namespace is, that's what you need to import.

Comment: The default namespace of my c# dll is "MyCSharpDll".
See the answer of @Steve, but still I don't understand why I cannot import my c# classes with complete imports statement, ie MyCShrapDl.MCSharpNamespac,e like for my other imports.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to your C# dll.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Now you can instantiate a C# class from VB.NET:

```
Dim cClass = New MyCSharpNamespace.MyCSharpClass()
```